# Flutter: Hide iframe src link

Tags: flutter, iframe

I want to hide the uri passed to the src of iframe so when inspected it would be hidden or encoded which is not human readable or can be copied and used.
[image: This is the link I want to hide/encrypt]

I have tried using flutter lib to encode uri.
I have tried passing a variable instead of the hardcoded link.
but none of them worked for me.

Comment: That isn't possible. You might want to look into protecting the iframe source with [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) instead

Comment: Thankyou Clive, I had a hint that this might not be possible and as far as I have searched I have came to know it isn't possible just as you said. So instead do you know is there a way to protect the embeded link to not be accessible outside the iframe?